# Mousedown event sensitivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a table grid that highlights cells/checkboxes with click and drag type of functionality.

When a user clicks on a cell and hovers for a while, then the cell / checkbox flickers a lot (firing off a lot of events).

Is there a way to make this less sensitive? i.e., some sort of timing event?

I tried adding .delay to the mouseover toggleclass, but it acts weird.

```
 $(function () {
        var isMouseDown = false,isHighlighted;

      $("#tablegrid").on('mousedown', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
            isMouseDown = true;
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
            isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
            var checkBoxes = $(this).find('.dosearchescheckbox :checkbox').trigger('click');
            return false; // prevent text selection
          })

      $("#tablegrid").on('mouseover', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
            if (isMouseDown) {
              $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
              var checkBoxes = $(this).find('.dosearchescheckbox :checkbox').trigger('click');     
            }
          })
      $("#tablegrid").bind('selectstart', 'td.nohighlight', function() {    
            return false;
          })

      $(document)
        .mouseup(function () {
          isMouseDown = false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Add a jsfiddle to help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't have anything in your hover handler that is preventing that sort of behavior. I'd recommend adding an external var to track it, and a 'mouseout' handler to track the end of the hover event, something like:

```
$(function () {
  let isMouseDown = false;
  let hasBeenClicked = false;
  let isHighlighted;
  $("#tablegrid").on('mousedown', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
    if (hasBeenClicked === false) {
      $(this).find('.dosearchescheckbox :checkbox').trigger('click');
      hasBeenClicked = true;
    }
    return false; // prevent text selection
  })
  $("#tablegrid").on('mouseover', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      if (hasBeenClicked === false) {
        $(this).find('.dosearchescheckbox :checkbox').trigger('click');
        hasBeenClicked = true;
      }
    }
  })
  // May or may not need this part depending on your app design
  $("#tablegrid").on('mouseout', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
    hasBeenClicked = false;
  })
  $("#tablegrid").bind('selectstart', 'td.nohighlight', function() {    
    return false;
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
    hasBeenClicked = false;
  });
});
```

The basic gist of this is that it sets a variable (`hasBeenClicked`) to true once the click has run once. It then checks against that before running the click trigger again. The reason for this is that the 'mouseover' event fires on every loop where the mouse is over an element, rather than just when the hover occurs. This prevents further logic from running once the click element has fired once.